# Jacoco report isn't excluding specified files

Tags: android, gradle, jacoco

I'm using Jacoco 0.8.5 and Gradle 6.4, I have an [Android project](https://github.com/Guimareshh/R6Companion) which I'm trying to setup my code coverage. Here is how my jacoco.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

def flavor = "debug"
def unitTestTask = "testDebugUnitTest"

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.5"
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    jacoco.includeNoLocationClasses = true
}

final androidExcludes =
        ["**/R.class",
         "**/R\$*.class",
         "**/BuildConfig.*",
         "**/Manifest*.*",
         "**/*Test*.*",
         "android/**/*.*",
         "**/*_MembersInjector.class",
         "**/Dagger*Component.class",
         "**/Dagger*Component\$Builder.class",
         "**/*Module_*Factory.class",
         "**/*_Provide*Factory*.*",
         "**/*_Factory*.*",
         "**/*Activity*.*",
         "**/*Fragment*.*",
         "**/*ViewHolder*.*",
         "**/*Adapter*.*"]


task jacocoReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: "${unitTestTask}") {
    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }

    afterEvaluate {

        def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "$project.buildDir/intermediates/javac/${flavor}/classes",
                excludes: androidExcludes)
        def kotlinDebugTree = fileTree(dir: "$project.buildDir/tmp/kotlin-classes/${flavor}/",
                excludes: androidExcludes)
        def mainSrc = "$project.projectDir/src/main/java"

        sourceDirectories.setFrom(files([mainSrc]))
        classDirectories.setFrom(files([debugTree], [kotlinDebugTree]))
        executionData.setFrom(fileTree(dir: project.buildDir, includes: ["jacoco/${unitTestTask}.exec"]))
    }
}
```

I want to remove from the coverage some files, set in androidExcludes, for example Activities or Adapter. But currently the report doesn't take into account my excludes, as you can see in the following report from CodeCov I still have excluded files (ViewHolder or Adapter)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

JaCoCo probably won't generate coverage reports, while there are no tests in `app/src/test` (or `app/src/androidTest` for integration tests). For JUnit 5 it also needs these dependencies:

```
dependencies {

    // (Required) Writing and executing Unit Tests on the JUnit Platform
    testImplementation ("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.2")
    testRuntimeOnly ("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.2")

    // (Optional) If you need "Parameterized Tests"
    testImplementation ("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.6.2")

    // (Optional) If you also have JUnit 4-based tests
    testImplementation ("junit:junit:4.13")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.6.2")

    androidTestImplementation ("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.2")

    // The instrumentation test companion libraries
    androidTestImplementation ("de.mannodermaus.junit5:android-test-core:1.2.0")
    androidTestRuntimeOnly ("de.mannodermaus.junit5:android-test-runner:1.2.0")

    // testImplementation ("androidx.test:core:1.2.0")
    // androidTestImplementation("androidx.test:runner:1.2.0")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test:rules:1.2.0")
}
```

[PR #23](https://github.com/Guimareshh/R6Companion/pull/23) fixes the tests. The output from `:jacocoTestReportDebug` looks alike this then:

[image: JaCoCo HTML Report]

Notice the `Created with JaCoCo 0.8.5.201910111838` at the bottom.

---

And for CodeCov, you'd need to add a `codecov.yml`; see [ignoring paths](https://docs.codecov.io/docs/ignoring-paths)
(the CodeCov configuration does not care about the JaCoCo configuration).

Comment: Hello thanks for taking so much time on this reply, much appreciated :)  About the jacoco report, it's already working fine I'm able to generate a report with my current settings. My main issue is to exclude specific classes from the coverage. It doesn't work from Jacoco, as it is shown in your report. And I tried to add a codecov.yml by specifying ignoring path but the result is still the same : classes I wanted to be exclude are still counted in the code coverage

Comment: I doubt that you where generating JaCoCo reports, with broken test tasks. And likely your `codecov.yml` configuration does not work either; where else shall the CodeCov GitHub app get it's configuration from?

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried to configure the gradle jacoco plugin specifically the exccludes:

```
test {
    jacoco {
        enabled = true
        destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/${name}.exec")
        includes = []
        excludes = []
        excludeClassLoaders = []
        includeNoLocationClasses = false
        sessionId = "<auto-generated value>"
        dumpOnExit = true
        classDumpDir = null
        output = JacocoTaskExtension.Output.FILE
        address = "localhost"
        port = 6300
        jmx = false
    }
}
```

source: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html

For me this is working fine. With this you can exclude complete packages `**/my/package/**`